# How to deal with this numerical integration problem of solving equations?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

My code：

```
Tc = 761.6;
F = Sqrt[9.1*10^(-31)/2/(1.28*10^(-23))/Tc];
Jc = 2.28;
d = 10^(-6);
Va = 100;
yc = Log[Jc/Ja];
ya = -2*(1.6*10^(-19))/(9.1*10^(-31))*F^2*Va + yc;

Xc = -NIntegrate[1/(Exp[Yc] - 1 + Exp[Yc]*Erf[Sqrt[Yc]] - 2*Sqrt[Yc/Pi])^(1/2), {Yc,0, yc}];
Xa = NIntegrate[1/(Exp[Ya] - 1 - Exp[Ya]*Erf[Sqrt[Ya]] + 2*Sqrt[Ya/Pi])^(1/2), {Ya,0, ya}];
NSolve[Xc + Xa - d*Sqrt[4*Pi/8.85*10^(-12)*Jc*F^3] == 0, Ja]
```

`Xc` and `Xa` are equations that require numerical integration methods to be solved.
Why can't I solve for the value of `Ja` by writing the code like above?

Comment: Changing last three  lines to `c[Ja_?NumericQ] := -NIntegrate[
    1/(Exp[Yc] - 1 + Exp[Yc]*Erf[Sqrt[Yc]] - 2*Sqrt[Yc/Pi])^(1/
        2), {Yc, 0, yc}];
Xa[Ja_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   1/(Exp[Ya] - 1 - Exp[Ya]*Erf[Sqrt[Ya]] + 2*Sqrt[Ya/Pi])^(1/2), {Ya,
     0, ya}];
NSolve[Xc + Xa - d*Sqrt[4*Pi/8.85*10^(-12)*Jc*F^3] == 0, Ja]` and executing the code, I obtain `{}` (no solution).

Comment: It should be `Xc[]Ja_?NumericQ]:=...` instead of `c[Ja_?NumericQ]:=....` in the above. Sorry  for the bad C&P.

Comment: Is there a sign error in your definition of `Xa`?  Currently it returns a complex number for all values of `Ja` that I've tried (using the above redefinition.)

Comment: This in turn appears to be occurring because your range of integration for `Ya` includes negative numbers, and the integrand is imaginary for $Y_a < 0$.

Comment: @Michael Seifert-Thanks for your comments, `ya` is greater than 0. Should I use`Abs` to limit the scope of `ya`  ?

Comment: @little_noob:  That depends entirely on the context of the problem you're trying to solve.  In your situation I would re-examine the assumptions I made in my derivation and figure out what the proper limits of integration should be, rather than just inserting absolute values willy-nilly.

Comment: @Michael Seifert-I can certainly comfirm that the range of `ya` is a real number greater than 0, but I still can't fix it out. : (